# Change the color of the button depending on the state of the variable in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button on which I send a request to Get, but I can not adjust the status of the button. That is, if global.urlScale is empty or zero, then the "Weigh" button should be gray, if on the contrary it is pink. Here is my code, thanks)

```html
              FlatButton(
                disabledColor: Colors.pink,
                textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Text('Weigh', textScaleFactor: 2),
                onPressed: global.urlScale  == "" ? null : () {
                  setState(() {
                    getUserDetails;
                  });
                },
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

U can declare u Color vairable in your class top and when once data is come u can change the color status in setState:

```
   Color buttonColor = Colors.transparent  // declare top of your widget class.

        FlatButton(
            disabledColor: Colors.pink,
            textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            color: buttonColor,
            child: Text('Weigh', textScaleFactor: 2),
            onPressed: global.urlScale  == "" ? null : () {
              setState(() {
                getUserDetails;
                 buttonColor = Colors.pink // change your button color code.
              });
            },
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
          ),
```